# How to map Ctrl/Shift to thumb buttons of Mouse?

Tags: hardware, mouse

I have an Microsoft Sidewinder X8 mouse and I wish to use <kbd>8</kbd> for <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the <kbd>9</kbd> for <kbd>Control</kbd>. Can anybody please tell me how?

Comment: `xbindkeys` solution below doesn't work for me, while `easystroke` seems overkill for my case. But this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587975/111262) from Unix&Linux works for me, it is _subjectively_ simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Install xdotool and xbindkeys

```
sudo apt-get install xdotools xbindkeys
```

Then copy the following code into ~/.xbindkeysrc

```
"xdotool keydown shift"
        b:9
"xdotool keyup shift"
        release + shift + b:9
"xdotool keydown ctrl"
        b:8
"xdotool keyup ctrl"
        release + control + b:8
```

where b:x is the number of your button which you can find out using xev.
As I don't want this bindig permanent everytime I need it I start a terminal and type `xbindkeys -n`. When I don't need it anymore I simply close the terminal.

Comment: That works well as far as mapping a button to a key goes. Sadly, it prevents the second mouse from getting recognized while the first one is held down.

Answer (score 2):

First install xdotool

```
sudo aptitude install xdotool
```

Then, you can create a script to simulate a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key press. Open gedit and copy paste the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

xdotool keydown ctrl

while [MOUSEKEYDOWN == 1]; do  #TODO change the while test.
sleep 30 
   #decrease sleep if script doesn't react fast enough on releasing the key, 
   #increase sleep if the computer uses to many CPU when pressing the button.
done

xdotool keyup ctrl # Lift the key back up after no button is pressed.
```

I'm not a great bash programmer. I need to search a way to identify if your button is down and I may have (more than one) syntax errors but I guess a bash programmer gets the idea.

If someone fixed the script, save it under ctrl.sh and make it executable

```
chmod +x ctrl.sh
```

Then, as nathwill said, go to system -> preferences -> keyboard. Add a custom command, choose to add the ~/ctrl.sh command and press your mouse button as shortkey.

This should do it.

Comment: The `xdotool` package looks like a promising direction but this isn't quite a full solution yet. Has somebody figured out how to use it to properly to detect mouse down / up events and trigger the desired modifier key equivalents?

Comment: `while xinput query-state <device name> | grep -Flq 'button[9]=down'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.x/2003-07/0010.html explains how to accomplish this using [xbindkeys](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xbindkeys) and [xmacroplay](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xmacrob:6) (from the xmacro package). Both of these applications are available from the Ubuntu repositories.

Here is an example from the site that explains how to map mouse button 6 to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left key</kbd> combination.

> Put this in `~/.xbindkeysrc` , and pressing mouse button 6 will echo the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left key</kbd> combination to the X server, which maps to "back" in  Konqueror and Mozilla :
>
> `"echo -e 'KeyStrPress Alt_L\nKeyStrPress Left\nKeyStrRelease Left\n
>   KeyStrRelease Alt_L' | xmacroplay &"
>
>   b:6`

There is Shift_L and Control_L (as well as Shift_R and Control_R if you prefer the right versions of the keys instead of the left versions). Simply substitute these keys into the above command, change b:6 to be the actual mouse button you want to map to the key, and put the command in `~/.xbindkeysrc`, and you should be all set.

Comment: The `xmacro` package was last updated in 2001. It does not compile on all distros (non Ubuntu here) any more due to major changes in the X system in the last nine years. Is there not another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**System** → **Preferences** → **Keyboard** shortcuts lets you map keys/buttons to commands; if that doesn't work `xbindkeys` is another great application for key mapping.

Comment: I know this works to bind a mouse click to a key event, but I've never gotten it to work as a modifier key. Do you have an example config that actually assigns shift/ctrl etc to a mouse event?

Answer (score 0):

there is a duplicate question: [Map Ctrl and Alt to mouse thumb buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162141/map-ctrl-and-alt-to-mouse-thumb-buttons)

so here's a copy of answer from this question, using `Easystroke`:

i found a working solution [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154356&p=12691359#post12691359). it uses Easystroke (`sudo apt install easystroke`). kudos to @stuartr from ubuntuforums!

though there was one issue - re-mapped mouse click sporadically fired an original ('back' in my case) event. to avoid this, mouse button can be remapped to some unused number with `xinput set-button-map` (`sudo apt install xinput`). i've put this into my `.xsessionrc` (taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903389/27202) by @Maxim):

```
mi_mouse_id=$(xinput | grep 'GTech MI wireless mouse.*pointer' | sed 's/.*\tid=\([0-9]*\)\t.*/\1/')
xinput set-button-map $mi_mouse_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 20 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

this maps mouse button 8 to button 20. hopefully button 20 has no meaning. at least it has absolutely no effect for me.
now it's time to re-map button 20 to Ctrl:

1. Preferences tab: additional buttons -> add -> radio button 'Instant Gestures' -> click the mouse button of choice in the grey area (for me a 'back, thumb button' became '(Instantly) Button 20')
2. Preferences tab: Select 'Autostart Easystroke'
3. Actions tab: Add Action
    Name: anything you like (e.g. 'Mouse 20 -> Ctrl')
    Type: 'Ignore'
    Details: click it once to change 'Ignore' to 'Key combination...'. then press Ctrl + a. 'a' doesn't matter and is ignored. 'Key Combination' will be replaced with 'Ctr'
4. With the new action selected/highlighted -> click 'Record Stroke' -> press the mouse button you're wanting to use again (this came up with '20 -> 20' in the Stroke column for me)
5. Now pressing and holding my mouse button brings up a dinky 'Ctr' on the screen and acts like the button is being held for as long as the mouse button is