# Map Ctrl and Alt to mouse thumb buttons

Tags: mouse, xbindkeys

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and have a multi-button Microsoft mouse. I would like to map the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier keys to the left and right thumb buttons of my mouse, respectively, so I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click without touching the keyboard.
My thumb buttons are buttons <kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>9</kbd>.

I tried the solution in [How do I configure a mouse thumb button?](https://askubuntu.com/q/52139/73396)
which explained how to map a double click to a <kbd>thumb button</kbd> - this worked for the double-click but I couldn't figure out how to modify the solution for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>

I also tried [How to map Ctrl/Shift to thumb buttons of Mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6134/73396)
which used xdotools and xbindkeys. I modified the script to this:

`~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool keydown alt"
        b:9
"xdotool keyup alt"
        release + alt + b:9
"xdotool keydown ctrl"
        b:8
"xdotool keyup ctrl"
        release + control + b:8
```

Which ALMOST works. It simulates a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key press when I click the left thumb button, but I can't actually hold the button and click at the same time - holding the <kbd>thumb button</kbd> seems to prevent it from listening to other input until it is released.

Does anyone know how I can make my mouse thumb button actually work as a modifier key, so I can use <kbd>thumb button</kbd> + click instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click?

Comment: Run `xev | grep button\|Button`, then, press the "Ctrl" tumb button over the white window, without releasing it, do a click, then release it and post the output.

Comment: @Helio see my newly created question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627555/how-to-map-modifiers-e-g-ctrl-to-mouse-thumb-buttons-using-xbindkeys

Answer (score 2):

i found a working solution [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154356&p=12691359#post12691359). it uses Easystroke (`sudo apt install easystroke`). kudos to @stuartr from ubuntuforums!

though there was one issue - re-mapped mouse click sporadically fired an original ('back' in my case) event. to avoid this, mouse button can be remapped to some unused number with `xinput set-button-map` (`sudo apt install xinput`).
to re-map on every login i've created (exacutable) `$HOME/.config/autostart/mouse-buttons.sh` with this content:

```
$ cat .config/autostart/mouse-buttons.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mi_mouse_id=$(xinput | grep 'GTech MI wireless mouse.*pointer' | sed 's/.*\tid=\([0-9]*\)\t.*/\1/')
xinput set-button-map $mi_mouse_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 20 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$
```

this maps mouse button 8 to button 20. hopefully button 20 has no meaning. at least it has absolutely no effect for me.
now it's time to re-map button 20 to Ctrl:

1. Preferences tab: additional buttons -> add -> radio button 'Instant Gestures' -> click the mouse button of choice in the grey area (for me a 'back, thumb button' became '(Instantly) Button 20')
2. Preferences tab: Select 'Autostart Easystroke'
3. Actions tab: Add Action
    Name: anything you like (e.g. 'Mouse 20 -> Ctrl')
    Type: 'Ignore'
    Details: click it once to change 'Ignore' to 'Key combination...'. then press Ctrl + a. 'a' doesn't matter and is ignored. 'Key Combination' will be replaced with 'Ctr'
4. With the new action selected/highlighted -> click 'Record Stroke' -> press the mouse button you're wanting to use again (this came up with '20 -> 20' in the Stroke column for me)
5. Now pressing and holding my mouse button brings up a dinky 'Ctr' on the screen and acts like the button is being held for as long as the mouse button is

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using xdotool, if you prefer a functional GUI-based solution, you can download the Easystrokes app from the Ubuntu software center.  You can easily map keyboard keys and shortcuts to mouse buttons and even mouse gestures.

Comment: I tried Easystrokes, but as far as I can tell, it won't allow me to map modifier keys to mouse buttons either. It will allow me to map a modifier+key combination, like SHIFT+A, but it won't let me map a modifier alone to a mouse button. I want holding down my mouse thumb button to have the same function as holding down the CTRL button.